# I want to postpone the conflict via script

Tags: svn, shell

I am writing wrappers for checkout and checkin. While checkout, I checkout the directory and lock the files mentioned or editing. But it may so happen that while checkout I get a conflict, I want to always postpone when conflict occurs, how can i do that via script

Comment: beforehand (before starting checkout) i need to know that a conflict will come. how can i check it?

Comment: I mean how do i answer the prompt via script?

Comment: Instead of adding comments to your own question, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I assume that when you say 'checkout' you really mean 'update'.
2. You can't know if a conflict will occur before issuing the command.
3. If you read the output of `svn help checkout` it gives you the answer to how to always postpone:

   ```
     --accept ARG             : specify automatic conflict resolution action
                               ('postpone', 'base', 'mine-conflict',
                                'theirs-conflict', 'mine-full', 'theirs-full',
                                'edit', 'launch')
   ```

Comment: Thanks Flimzy. I was not knowing --accept argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress all prompts during subversion operations you can also pass

```
--non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
```